# Date in VBA form

Tags: forms, date, excel, vba

On my excel form I would like for my date to auto populate with today's date, I tried using the `=Today()` function but when I submitted after filling out the form it only appears to update it once.I need it to work each time I press the submit button. Any help/advice anyone could give would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks
Paula

Comment: Is this for a textbox on a userform? If so you'd put something like `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Me.TextBox1 = Date
End Sub` in the forms code.

Comment: Thanks for this however it still doesn’t update the date each time I submit the form

Comment: What kind of button do you use? Does it call a macro? Where is the date you want to change located?

Comment: I have a submit button which is a command button, no this part of my code doesnt link back to a macro only the initial opening of the form is linked to a macro and the date I would like to change is located at the bottom of my userform in a textbox...do you need me to supply any of the code I currently have?

Comment: Then I suppose you have some code inside of a procedure called something like `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`, which decides what happens when you push the submit button? Insert the line `Me.TextBox1 = Date` into that procedure, and I think it should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, I would recommend using a UserForm! Then in the code for that form, you can simply insert:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() Project.MyTxtBox = Date End Sub
```

I would recommend  [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html)  resource for learning more about the possibilities of UserForms.

**Edit**: If you want to populate on the `Submit` button, you must find the initialization procedure for the click on that button. It will end in ..`_Click()`. Within that procedure you will have to add `Project.MyTxtBox = Date` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the link that should come in very handy. I have created this within a userform however I cant get the date to work so I tried putting it out on the main user form template to see if it would make a difference. I seem to be getting an error with the code you suggested based on the Project part

Comment: Well yes, you need to replace `Project.MyTxtBox` with whatever your respective UserForm and textbox are named. That part is arbitrary.

Comment: Sorry forgot to update the project name..I tired that but its only populating the first submit again

Comment: I was able to add it in as a single line after my add command `Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

BSPersonalData.txtdatecompleted = Date` and it seems to be working fine now. Thankyou for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for this in VBA you would select your Developer tab, click on Visual Basic, create a new method, then paste this code in.

```
    Sub tDate()
Range("A1") = Date
End Sub
```

after that link the button to the macro you just created. Every time the macro runs it will give you the current date.